# Intellij IDEA Tips

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains

I need help. How can I add this green block(show context actions on img) to my IDE? Can't find it in settings.
[image: idea]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зеленое окно на скрине — Presentation assistant. Это плагин, который показывает всплывающее уведомление каждый раз, когда вы выполняете действие в IDEA. Он показывает, какое действие было выполнено и какое сочетание клавиш связано с ним.

Чтобы у вас всплывало аналогичное окно, установите в IDEA этот плагин

Comment: Понял, спасибо!